# AWS AppSync React: how to work with "complex" GraphQL schema?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-dynamodb, graphql, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

I am trying to get started with [AWS AppSync](https://aws.amazon.com/appsync) and [AWS Amplify](https://aws-amplify.github.io).

So far, I managed to follow the AWS documentation (especially [here](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/api) and [here](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/react)) to successfully create a [sample TODO app](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/api#react-components) (third code snippet) and enable the AppSync GraphQL API like so:

```
$ amplify add api
? Please select from one of the below mentioned services GraphQL
? Provide API name: MySampleTodoAPI
? Choose an authorization type for the API API key
? Do you have an annotated GraphQL schema? No
? Do you want a guided schema creation? true
? What best describes your project: Single object with fields (e.g., “Todo” with ID, name, description)
```

This generates this "trivial" `schema.graphql` (i.e. containing only a single object):

```
type Todo @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  description: String
}
```

`amplify push` generates a much more involved, secondary `schema.graphql` from the file above, creates JavaScript code with objects for mutations, queries, etc. and also sets up AWS resources (i.e. DynamoDB table, S3 buckets, etc.). The app seems to have bugs, but essentially works - including adding data entered in the UI to the DynamoDB table.

I have created a second sample Blog app in the same way as above, only this time choosing `Single object with fields (e.g., “Todo” with ID, name, description)` instead of `Single object with fields ...`.

This generates this "complex" `schema.graphql` (i.e. containing multiple, connected objects):

```
type Blog @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  posts: [Post] @connection(name: "BlogPosts")
}
type Post @model {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  blog: Blog @connection(name: "BlogPosts")
  comments: [Comment] @connection(name: "PostComments")
}
type Comment @model {
  id: ID!
  content: String
  post: Post @connection(name: "PostComments")
}
```

**Question:** How do I deal with "complex" objects in a React application when talking to the AWS AppSync GraphQL backend ?

As a (contrived) example, assuming I want to add a new `Blog` object with one `Post` and one `Comment` object, can I somehow pass all objects to a single mutation in a single `Connect` React component ? Or do I have to first trigger a `Blog` mutation, followed by the other two ? Or do I have to look into customizing the (secondary) `schema.graphql` and JavaScript files that Amplify generates for me ?

Unfortunately, the AWS sample code only deals with "trivial" schemas, not "complex" ones - and Amplify seems to be so fresh out of the box that all the third party posts and sample projects use other technologies...

Thank you very much for your consideration! :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just to distinguish, Complex Objects is a term used by AWS AppSync to denote working with S3 metadata. In your question by complex, you mean non-trivial schemas.

As I understand this, you would like to to save a bunch of related types using a single mutation. AWS AppSync lets you manage your GraphQL schema, attach datasources to the fields, write custom logic via the VTL resolvers. It also exposes a context variable that holds your query arguments, result from the parent resolvers, utility functions, etc. So you can use these to get what you want. Otherwise, like you had mentioned, you would from your React app first make a mutation to save a blog, followed by other types.

Here are some of the ways you can write a single mutation for related GraphQL types:

- Once you create a new GraphQL API using AWS Amplify, you can still go to your AppSync schema (on the AWS Console), and add a new mutation type and custom resolver to handle this single mutation. Since your datasource for the types are all in DynamoDB, you can use BatchWrite across multiple tables.
- We introduced a concept of [pipeline resolvers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/pipeline-resolvers.html) in the last week. Using this, you can attach a pipeline resolver to the mutation type by passing Blog, Post and Comments to a chain of functions, which update the corresponding DynamoDB tables accordingly.
- Use a Lambda datasource which updates all 3 tables in one go.
- Update the CloudFormation document generated by AWS Amplify, or create a new child CF stack for the same
- Add your own transformer to model your custom resolvers that update all 3 tables in one go, using one of the above approaches.

AWS Amplify would not be able to provide this functionality out of the box, as this will then be too opinionated and use case driven. In many cases it may not be a good idea to write to multiple tables in one go without thinking about making this transactional and apply proper error handling.

We are figuring out several ways to improve the Developer Experience, and you should see some updates in the near future.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! It seems there is a lot of valuable information in it, but for the moment, I had to halt work on the GraphQL API and postpone that until I have learned more about Amplify, React and JavaScript in general. I will get back to this eventually.

Comment: Would be nice, if there would be more tutorials about it. I understand, that editing CF templates is not much Youtube friendly, but transactions in AWS Amplify are not documented very well.